# Fullcalendar v2.x month view bug on IE8

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8, calendar, fullcalendar

I have a problem using Fullcalendar (v2+) : monthView seems to be broken on IE8 even on a minimal install from the demonstration pages. All other viewModes are OK.

See this fiddle for reproduction (on IE8) : http://jsfiddle.net/pn6u3oa7/embedded/result/
If you load this same fiddle on Chrome or FF, you'll see the correct rendering.

And a capture of the bug : [image]

JS code is from documentation and is very minimal :

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    header: {
      left: 'prev,next today',
      center: 'title',
      right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
    },
    defaultDate: '2014-06-12',
    defaultView: 'month',
    editable: true,
    events: [
      {
        title: 'All Day Event',
        start: '2014-06-01'
      }
    ]
  });
});
```

Maybe I am missing something ?

Thanks

Comment: I found one other mention of this in a comment on a Adam's blog post: http://blog.arshaw.com/1/post/2014/11/fullcalendar-220-released.html I suggest varying the jquery version and then adding it to the issue tracker. And if it's in production already, rollback to a working FC version.

Comment: Thanks, I already created an issue here : http://code.google.com/p/fullcalendar/issues/detail?id=2428

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is already a solution for the problem:

The bug fix is documented [here](https://github.com/arshaw/fullcalendar/commit/87cfc4f74361f8368b13c8e647de5c26bcce56ec).

This fix is not included in the current version of fullcalendar 2.2.7, but should be in the next version.

So everybody who encounters the problem, wait for the version >2.2.7 or install the fix by hand. I have included the fix in my version and it worked.